# Executing 2 commands

Tags: python, authentication, discord

Hey im working on a discord bot and im kind of new to python and im having a problem with my if statements im making a login system and it and its executing 2 commands and i only want it to execute 1 here is my code

```
@client.command()
async def login(ctx, *, username=None, password=None):
    if username == None:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, please enter your username to log in!')
    elif password == None:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, please enter your password to log in!')
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, Login Successful!')
```

here is the result im getting when i execute the login command

[image]

but i only need this command to show

[image]

Comment: I'm not familiar with discord bots however I can say from looking at the code snippet that it is likely some other snippet of code that is triggering the `welcome back` message.

Comment: Do you have a `on_member_join`?  I bet that is triggering it.  https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_join

Comment: Or possible `on_member_update`?  https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.on_member_update

Answer (score 0):

From your code, I see that after if statements checked the username and password, your code did not try stop continuing whatever is below the thread (I'm assuming that you did not put the rest of your login-successful-code in the else statement because from the image the `ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, Login Successful!')` did not get executed). In other words, you need to break out of the function after seeing that the username or password is `None`.

An easy way to fix this is to add `return` after outputting the errors:

```py
@client.command()
async def login(ctx, *, username=None, password=None):
    if username == None:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, please enter your username to log in!')
        return
    elif password == None:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, please enter your password to log in!')
        return
    else:
        await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention}, Login Successful!')
```

Or you can put everything in your else statement.

One quick note that I have noticed in your code is that you used a wildcard "`*`" in your arguments: `(ctx, *, username=None, password=None)`. In discord.py, when you enter a command in discord chat (e.g. `!log name 1234`). The string "name 1234" will be set into the `username` variable.